# Does not conform the expected type

Tags: scala

I have following code snippet:

```
  def determineProducerType(keySerializer: KkSerializer)(valueSerializer: KkSerializer)(props: Properties)
  : Eval[KafkaProducer[java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object]] = (keySerializer, valueSerializer) match {

    case (KkStringSeDe, KkStringSeDe) => Later(new KafkaProducer[String, String](props))
    case (KkStringSeDe, KkByteArraySeDe) => Later(new KafkaProducer[String, Byte](props))
    case (KkStringSeDe, KkIntegerSeDe) => Later(new KafkaProducer[String, Integer](props))
    case (KkStringSeDe, KkLongSeDe) => Later(new KafkaProducer[String, Long](props))

  }
```

The compiler complains:

```
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /home/developer/Desktop/scala/PureProducer/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/scala/PureProducer/src/main/scala/TheProducer.scala:113:48: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer[String,String]
[error]  required: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer[Object,Object]
[error] Note: String <: Object, but Java-defined class KafkaProducer is invariant in type K.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error] Note: String <: Object, but Java-defined class KafkaProducer is invariant in type V.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]     case (KkStringSeDe, KkStringSeDe) => Later(new KafkaProducer[String, String](props))
[error]                                                ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/scala/PureProducer/src/main/scala/TheProducer.scala:114:51: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer[String,Byte]
[error]  required: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer[Object,Object]
[error]     case (KkStringSeDe, KkByteArraySeDe) => Later(new KafkaProducer[String, Byte](props))
[error]                                                   ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/scala/PureProducer/src/main/scala/TheProducer.scala:115:49: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer[String,Integer]
[error]  required: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer[Object,Object]
[error] Note: String <: Object, but Java-defined class KafkaProducer is invariant in type K.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error] Note: Integer <: Object, but Java-defined class KafkaProducer is invariant in type V.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]     case (KkStringSeDe, KkIntegerSeDe) => Later(new KafkaProducer[String, Integer](props))
[error]                                                 ^
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/scala/PureProducer/src/main/scala/TheProducer.scala:116:46: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer[String,Long]
[error]  required: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer[Object,Object]
[error]     case (KkStringSeDe, KkLongSeDe) => Later(new KafkaProducer[String, Long](props))
[error]                                              ^
[error] four errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Nov 12, 2017 10:39:14 AM
```

What I am trying to do is, I defined a sum type:

```
sealed trait KkSerializer
case object KkStringSeDe extends KkSerializer
case object KkByteArraySeDe extends KkSerializer
case object KkIntegerSeDe extends  KkSerializer
case object KkLongSeDe extends KkSerializer
```

When it matches an appropriate sum type, then it should returns     corresponding type.

Create an instance of `KafkaProducer` is:

```
val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Your function definition states clearly it must return `Eval[KafkaProducer[A, B]]`. There is absolutely no guarantee/obligation for `A` and `B` to be of any concrete type `String/Integer/Long`, hence the error.

Comment: Please, post your error, not a picture of your error. This is a programmer Q&A site, [photography.se] is over there.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you can just use path dependent types to get what you want:

```
sealed trait KkSerializer { type Out }
case object KkStringSeDe extends KkSerializer {
  type Out = String
}
case object KkByteArraySeDe extends KkSerializer {
  type Out = Byte
}

def determineProducerType(k: KkSerializer)(v: KkSerializer)(props: Properties): Eval[KafkaProducer[k.Out, v.Out]] =
  Later(new KafkaProducer[k.Out, v.Out](props))
```